# How can I use little-o notation in calculus?

Tags: calculus, analysis, asymptotics

Suppose that $\frac{p_n}{(\lambda_n \rho_n)^k}=o(\rho_n ^k)$, where $k$ is a positive integer, and the condition about $\rho_n$ is that $M_3n^{-c_1/2} \leq \rho_n \leq M_1$, where $0 \leq c_1 \leq 1/2$, $M_1$ and $M_3$ are positive constants. Then how can I derive $\frac{p_n}{(\lambda_n \rho_n)^k} \rightarrow 0$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

My thought is as follow

Since $\frac{p_n}{(\lambda_n \rho_n)^k}=o(\rho_n ^k)$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{p_n}{(\lambda_n \rho_n)^k \rho_n^k}=0 $.

Since $\rho_n \leq M_1$, $\rho_n^k \leq M_1^k$. Then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{p_n}{(\lambda_n \rho_n)^k M_1^k}=0 $.

I derive that $\frac{p_n}{(\lambda_n \rho_n)^k}=o(M_1^k)=M_1 ^ko(1) \rightarrow 0$.

However, my supervisor said it is wrong. How can I derive $\frac{p_n}{(\lambda_n \rho_n)^k} \rightarrow 0$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: If $p_n^k$ is bounded then $o(p_n^k) \subset o(1)$ and so $p_n/(\lambda_n p_n)^k = o(1)$, which means precisely that $p_n/(\lambda_n p_n)^k \to 0$. Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: The denominator is $(\lambda_n \rho_n)^k$, which is different from $p_n^k$. And also $o(\rho_n^k)$ is not $o(p_n^k)$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that there was $\rho$ and $p$. Here's my corrected comment: If $\rho_n$ is bounded then $\rho_n^k$ is bounded, and so $o(\rho_n^k) \subset o(1)$ and it then follows that $p_n/(\lambda_n \rho_n)^k \in o(1)$, which means precisely that $p_n/(\lambda_n \rho_n)^k \to 0$.